# What are the steps to implement Google Button subscribe for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I implemented Facebook Button with omniauth and It works. I don't find a tutorial to implement Google Button. Could you guide me or share some steps to integate it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://richonrails.com/articles/google-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails) you can find a tutorial:

**Gemfile:**

```
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2", "~> 0.2.1"
```

**config/initializers/omniauth.rb:**

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, 'my Google client id', 'my Google client secret', {client_options: {ssl: {ca_file:        Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}}
end
```

**Terminal Commands:**

```
rails g model user provider uid name oauth_token oauth_expires_at:datetime
rake db:migrate
```

**Terminal Commands:**

```
rails g controller home show
rails g controller Sessions create destroy
```

**config/routes.rb:**

```
GoogleAuthExample::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

  resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resource :home, only: [:show]

  root to: "home#show"
end
```

**app/models/user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Auth Example App</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <% if current_user %>
        Signed in as <strong><%= current_user.name %></strong>!
        <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, id: "sign_out" %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Sign in with Google", "/auth/google_oauth2", id: "sign_in" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you I try it but do I have to generate another model because I have ever installed Facebook?

Comment: Do I have to put the secret key in application.yml?